# In ransack, how to create search attributes based on associated records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

In my project, I have the following model:

```
Product:
  #string  :name
  has_many :questions
  has_many :orders

Question:
  #string :name
  belongs_to :product

Order:
  belongs_to :product
  has_many :answers

Answer:
  #string :answer
  belongs_to :question
```

In other words, a product has a bunch of questions, and an order, which belongs to a product, has answers to all that product's questions.

Now, I want to select a product, and use Ransack to search for orders for that product, **in such a way that the questions of that product become search attributes**.

Example:

```
Product (name = 'Product_foo')
  Question (name = 'Full name')
  Question (name = 'Age')
```

Then, in the search form, I want search fields to be available for orders, to filter them on full name and age.

How do I do this?